# LINQ query for string.replace

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Looking for help where given any string, return a string with alphanumeric characters only and replace all non-alphanumeric characters with _

so string 
"ASD@#$123" becomes
"ASD___123"

etc

thanks

Comment: return txt.Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray()) shrinks the string, still thinking of how to replace them :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace all Special Characters in a string IN C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778879/replace-all-special-characters-in-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For most string operations, you would be better off (in terms of <strike>both efficiency and</strike> conciseness) if you use regular expressions rather than LINQ:

```
string input = "ASD@#$123";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[^A-Z0-9]", "_", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you want to preserve any Unicode alphanumeric character, including non-ASCII letters such as `é`, we can use the [non-word character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#NonWordCharacter) class to make it even simpler:

```
string input = "ASD@#$123";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\W", "_");
```

For the sake of comparison, here is the same conversion done using LINQ (allowing just ASCII letters and digits):

```
string input = "ASD@#$123";
string result =
    new string(input.Select(c => 
        c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? c : '_'
    ).ToArray());
```

Or, if `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` meets your requirements:

```
string input = "ASD@#$123";
string result = 
    new string(input.Select(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) ? c : '_').ToArray());
```

Note that `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` will allow non-ASCII letters, and is comparable to the `\w` word character class whose negation was used in our second example.

**Edit**: As Steve Wortham has observed, the LINQ versions are actually more than 3× faster than the regex (even when a `Regex` instance is created in advance with `RegexOptions.Compiled` and re-used).

Comment: `Ö` or `α` ,for ex, are  alphanumeric chars :)

Comment: @L.B: Since this is a redaction operation, it’s more reasonable to assume that non-ASCII characters are not permitted (although I made a note to that effect at the end).

Comment: @L.B: For the sake of clarity, I’ve added another example which preserves Unicode letters.

Comment: +1.  Although I must note that even though your first Regex solution is concise, it is over 3 times slower than your Linq solutions.  It helps somewhat to enable RegexOptions.Compiled, but Linq still wins the race easily.

Comment: @SteveWortham: Strange… Let me test it out on my end.

Comment: @SteveWortham: I managed to reproduce the same performances you reported on my machine. I never expected that… Thanks for the heads-up. I’ve amended my answer.

Comment: Sure.  The OP didn't ask for the absolute fastest solution, but I still feel compelled to run benchmarks now and then. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] unwanted = new[] {'@', '#', '$'};

foreach(var x in query)
{
    x.SomePropertyName = string.Join("_", x.SomePropertyName.Split(unwanted));
};
```

[LINQ lambda expression to replace multiple characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709924/linq-lambda-expression-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function for you:

```
    String ReplaceWrongChars(String baseString)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        String rv = rx.Replace(baseString, "_");

        return rv;
    }
```

If you do not need spaces included, use "[^A-Za-z0-9]" as regular expression.